# Composite REST Resource Not Found

Tags: rest-api, callout, apexrest, composite

I created a composite REST to insert opportunity for existing account, but all the GET method return error resource not found.. someone help

```
{
"allOrNone" : true,
"compositeRequest" : [{
    "method" : "GET",
    "referenceId" : "GetAccountId",
    "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+SAP_Account_Id__c=1213019"
},
{
    "method" : "GET",
    "referenceId" : "GetAccountDivisionId",
    "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id+from+Account_Division__r+where+SAP_External_Key__c='1213019'"
},
{
    "method" : "GET",
    "referenceId" : "GetSalesOfficeId",
    "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id+from+Sales_Office__r+where+SAP_External_Key__c='1213019'"
},
{
    "method":"POST",
    "url":"/services/data/v45.0/composite/tree/Opportunity",
    "referenceId":"CreateOpportunity",
    "body": {
        "attributes" : {"type" : "Opportunity", "referenceId" : "CreateOpportunity"},
        "name" : "Test",
        "AccountId" : "@{GetAccountId.records[0].Id",
        "Account_Division__r" : "@{GetAccountDivisionId.records[0].id}",
        "Plant__c" : "JKT",
        "Amount_Estimated__c" : "1000",
        "SAP_Inquiry_ID__c" : "INQ121319",
        "Sales_Office__r" : "@{GetSalesOfficeId.records[0].id}",
        "Inquiry_Amount_Original_Currency__c" : "1000",
        "Exchange_Rate__c" : "14000",
        "CloseDate" : "2019-12-30T18:25:43.511Z",
        "StageName" : "Preparation",
        "Data_Synced_to_SAP__c" : true,
        "LeadSource" : "Other"
    }
}]
```

}

Comment: Is it working if you use only the request `/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+SAP_Account_Id__c=1213019` in Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query from either `Account_Division__r` or `Sales_Office__r`. The `__r` notation is for relationships. These are the 'REST Resource(s) not found'

If they are relationships to Contact, you would need to query the SObject(s) and use the Id from Contact to limit the query further. You need to replace `__r` with `__c` to access the SObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of a 404 in a composite REST is if you do the following:

where your URL that includes the above body is at a version earlier than the urls of the component requests.  For example, if you used curl or Workbench and did:

```
/services/data/v41.0/composite
```

where the POST body was:

```
{
"allOrNone" : true,
"compositeRequest" : [{
    "method" : "GET",
    "referenceId" : "GetAccountId",
    "url" : "/services/data/v42.0/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+SAP_Account_Id__c=1213019"
}]
```

The `/services/data/v42.0/query` resource would not be found because the API is executing at version 41